# How to prevent Firefox >80 to cache redirect target pages?

Tags: php, html, firefox, caching, browser-cache

I am having some [cache issues with grav cms](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-login/issues/264) lately. The developers currently have no solution yet, so I want to use the time to better understand caching and maybe solve the problem myself.

I have a normal page and a redirect link that adds a message to the page

- /page.html
- /redirect.html -> /page.html (with an additional message)

However, the additional message is only shown when I press f5 in the browser, and will only disappear when I reload the page again. Firefox >80 (not with chrome or other browsers) seems to cache the page more aggressively. But how can I prevent this cache, without disabling cache for all pages?

I've inspected the following:

1. When opening the redirect page a 302 will be sent to the browser. This redirect has the header: `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate` set.
2. The browser still loads the HTML page from the cache. I verified that by the firefox dev tool and the server log.
3. Since the browser does not reload the page, I don't even have any chance to force a reload via etag.

Do I need to add an etag to the redirect 302 answer or is this a firefox issue I need to file at their bug tracker?

Now if I press f5 the message will show. If I then open up the page again, the message is still there (it should disappear). It seems that independent from the redirect, the etag is also not really working. There is not even a website request from firefox, so the backend handling should not be the problem. Maybe the etag is set wrong? Or with the wrong header? example etag: `ETag: 09fb2b656ceed6e8ca1e7bc042e3a094`

Edit:
It turns out the following setting works for me, but is it really the correct way to enable caching with etags?

```yaml
  expires: 3600
  cache_control: 'private, max-age=0, must-revalidate'
  etag: true
```